# how to parse a request in a node.js server built on net module

Tags: parsing, node.js, module, request

We are building a server with net module, and having hard time extracting the URL (and resource path) from the request. The following code crashes, saying:

```
Parameter 'url' must be a string not undefined.
```

File `netServer.js`:

```
var net = require('net');
var url = require('url');

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) { //'connection' listener

   socket.on('connect', function(request) {
   });

  socket.on('data', function(request) {
      var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
      console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

  });

  socket.on('end', function() {

  });

});
server.listen(8080, function() { //'listening' listener
    console.log('server bound');
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to build an HTTP server? net is a TCP package, so all you get is the remoteAddress and remotePort, the rest will be sent on the data handler (which is just passed a Buffer, or a string, depending on the encoding).

Use the HTTP module for this, because it does all of the parsing for you.